# output printing multiple times in a loop

Tags: python

Im trying to write a function that outputs all the prime numbers between a certain range that ends with 7. However when I run the program it gives me numerous outputs of the same number. I think it has something to do with the loop but I dont know what to fix.

```
lower=int(input('enter lower bound: '))
upper=int(input('enter upper bound: '))

for i in range(lower, upper + 1):
   if i > 1:
       for x in range(2, i):
           if (i % x) == 0:
               break
           elif i%10==7:
               print(i)
```

Comment: You need to only `print(i)` after you've confirmed that it has no factors, so outside of the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now the `elif` is related to this `if`, so when you're testing `17` for all number that are not a divisor of `17` you're going into the `elif` and print it

```
if (i % x) == 0:
    break
elif i%10==7:
    print(i)
```

---

## Fix with a `for-else`

Use the `for-else`, if the loop encounter no `break` it goes into the `else` (if there is one), here you can add your condition

```
for i in range(lower, upper + 1):
    if i > 1:
        for x in range(2, i):
            if (i % x) == 0:
                break
        else:
            if i % 10 == 7:
                print(i)
```

---

## Improve

Then you can imagine, to check prime only for `..7` numbers, this will avoid a huge amount of computing. Also to remove the `if i>1` which is quickly useless, use `max` on the lower bound, if you set like a negative value, it'll start at 2, no empty run, and end the testing loop at `sqrt(i)` because you won't find a divisor after its square root

```
from math import sqrt

for i in range(max(lower, 2), upper + 1):
    if i % 10 == 7:
        for x in range(2, int(sqrt(i))):
            if (i % x) == 0:
                break
        else:
            print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(min(lower,2), upper + 1):
    if i % 10 == 7:
        for x in range(2, i):
           if (i % x) == 0:
               break
        else:
            print(i)
```